# Error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, rest

Can you help me about this problem? I hope you to answer this problem as soon as possible, because this assignment will be collected tomorrow. Thanks in advance.

I have script like this in "buku.php"

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
include "koneksi.php";

$path = $_SERVER[PATH_INFO];
if($path != null)
{
    $path_params = spliti("/".$path);
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($input);

    foreach($xml->mahasiswa as $mahasiswa)
    {
        $querycek = "SELECT * FROM mahasiswa WHERE token = '$mahasiswa->token'";
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($querycek);

        if($num_rows == 0)
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO mahasiswa(token, password, nomor_id, nama_lengkap, tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin, agama, asal_sekolah, jurusan_sekolah, rata_rata_nem, alamat, kewarganegaraan, provinsi, kabupaten_kota, kode_pos, telepon, email, pilihan_1, pilihan_2) VALUES ('$mahasiswa->token', '$mahasiswa->password', '$mahasiswa->nomor_id', '$mahasiswa->nama_lengkap', '$mahasiswa->tanggal_lahir', '$mahasiswa->jenis_kelamin', '$mahasiswa->agama', '$mahasiswa->asal_sekolah', '$mahasiswa->jurusan_sekolah', '$mahasiswa->rata_rata_nem', '$mahasiswa->alamat', '$mahasiswa->kewarganegaraan', '$mahasiswa->provinsi', '$mahasiswa->kabupaten_kota', '$mahasiswa->kode_pos', '$mahasiswa->telepon', '$mahasiswa->email', '$mahasiswa->pilihan_1', '$mahasiswa->pilihan_2')";
        }
        elseif($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $query = "UPDATE mahasiswa SET nomor_id='$mahasiswa->nomor_id', nama_lengkap='$mahasiswa->nama_lengkap', tanggal_lahir='$mahasiswa->tanggal_lahir', jenis_kelamin='$mahasiswa->jenis_kelamin', agama='$mahasiswa->agama', asal_sekolah='$mahasiswa->asal_sekolah', jurusan_sekolah='$mahasiswa->jurusan_sekolah', rata_rata_nem='$mahasiswa->rata_rata_nem', alamat='$mahasiswa->alamat', kewarganegaraan='$mahasiswa->kewarganegaraan', provinsi='$mahasiswa->provinsi', kabupaten_kota='$mahasiswa->kabupaten_kota', kode_pos='$mahasiswa->kode_pos', telepon='$mahasiswa->telepon', email='$mahasiswa->email', pilihan_1='$mahasiswa->pilihan_1', pilihan_2='$mahasiswa->pilihan_2' WHERE token='$mahasiswa->token'";
        }

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: '.mysql_error());
    }
}
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE')
{
    $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($input);
    foreach ($xml->mahasiswa as $mahasiswa)
    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM mahasiswa WHERE token='$mahasiswa->token'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: '.mysql_error());
    }
}
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
    if($path_params[1] != null)
    {
        $query = "SELECT token, password, nomor_id, nama_lengkap, tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin, agama, asal_sekolah, jurusan_sekolah, rata_rata_nem, alamat, kewarganegaraan, provinsi, kabupaten_kota, kode_pos, telepon, email, pilihan_1, pilihan_2 FROM mahasiswa WHERE token='$path_params[1]'";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT token, password, nomor_id, nama_lengkap, tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin, agama, asal_sekolah, jurusan_sekolah, rata_rata_nem, alamat, kewarganegaraan, provinsi, kabupaten_kota, kode_pos, telepon, email, pilihan_1, pilihan_2 FROM mahasiswa WHERE token='';";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: '.mysql_error());

    echo "<data>";
    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<mahasiswa>";
        foreach($line as $key => $col_value)
        {
            echo "<$key>$col_value</$key>";
        }
        echo "</mahasiswa>";
    }
    echo "</data>";

    mysql_free_result($result);
}

mysql_close($link);
```

?>

When I run this in my browser, it looks like this.
[image: Error]

For additional information, this is my database in "phpmyadmin"
[image: Error description]

Comment: In the code, please comment beside the line.

Comment: the `spliti` function is deprecated, better to use `preg_split`. That said - what is the actual problem - it is unclear from the description or screenshots

Comment: Still error... error on line 2 at column 1